# Magento 2 Nav Element Case Issue

Tags: magento2

I having an issue with the categories changing case between the backend and the frontend. I have a category 'ATV' which should be uppercase and is in the backend as you can see in the image, but when it is displayed as a nav element in the front end it is only capitalized. Is this just how Magento displays categories or does it have something to do with the theme? I could handle it with some css but was wondering if there was a way to make it honor what is in the backend.

[image]

[image]

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are any settings on a different scope that are overriding it?  i.e. Have you checked any settings for the category after `changing the Store View`?

Comment: @mtr.web this was it, thanks for pointing it out I feel like a dummy

Comment: Happy to help.  This has happened to m often when using a third-party application to add/update category data.